Device for bootloader installation is grayed out
I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04. I used a 32GB flash drive to boot from. I got up to the part in the installation where it asked me what I wanted to install. I don’t want to do a clean install, but for some reason the option to dual install doesn't show up.
I tried a few things but I couldn't get it to appear as an option, so I decided to go with the manual installation. After partitioning off about 52 GB (I did this in Windows and then switched back to Ubuntu), I made a / partition and a /home partition, but I can't select a place to install the OS. When I click the dropdown menu, my SSD is grayed out.

I'm new to Linux, so apologies in advance for my follow up/clarification questions.

Is sda1 the ESP - efi system partition? And your sizes for / & /home are smallish. Better then just to have one larger / (root) partition, so you do not have to manage size of each. One may fill up sooner depending on your use.

@DavidDE apologies, I have added it in.

@oldfred sda1 is of type VFAT with no mount point. Again, I’m new to the Linux scene so hopefully that answers your question.

The ESP must be FAT32 or vfat, but also have boot,esp flags. Windows fast startup or  with some systems, a UEFI system setting may lock the ESP. Check Windows settings & fast start up is off and UEFI settings.

Looks like you have only one device, so the device for bootloader is preselected and greyed out, no change possible.  You OS install location has been selected when you set the "/" root location. The other required mount is the EFI partition at /boot/efi, presumably sda1, but not shown in the picture. That partition should have the esp and boot flags, and its type should be recognized as the EFI partition. When all required mounts are selected, click on the "next" button to proceed.

The next button is also grayed out. Clicking on it has no results.

If you are using a custom (GPT) partition layout, you need to create a 2048 Sector long "BIOS Boot" -partition as the first partition.
You can do this also manually during the installer for example like this:

Switch to TTY2 by clicking ctrl-alt-F2
sudo su
cfdisk /dev/sda (if cfdisk is not installed, you can: apt install cfdisk)
Then fix the layout appropriately, for example by deleting the old partitions (this will delete all old data, so backup first if you need them), and then creating a new first partition that has size of 2048S (sectors). Then change the type to "BIOS Boot"
Switch back to TTY2 by ctrl-alt-F1
Potentially go back, and then choose again Custom Layout to re-read the partitions
Now you should be able to choose the disk as boot disk.


I had the same problem because I made 2 mistakes

When try to boot from the installation flash disk, it gives you 2 options, one to use it as UEFI and one without (presumably BIOS) . Here, I had to choose the right one , UEFI in my case as my SSD is formatted in UEFI.
I had to use gparted to create a small fat32 partition and then, using the option "manage flags" to tick ESP, boot is automatically ticked also.
Then, everything worked

